# Final Cut Pro 10.1: How to move clip framewise in timeline?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

in Final Cut Pro X 10.08 I have been able to move a clip frame wise with the arrow key. In 10.1 this moves the cursor, not the clip. Is there a way to move the clip?

Kind regards,

Nils

Comment: I don't have FCP 10.1 so this is a guess, but have you tried selecting the clip first or using any of the modifier keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the comma and period keys to nudge the clip left and right, respectively.